# Dispatch key event back to the previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity, dispatchevent

I have a edit-text on one of my activity in which the user has to enter an already given text. After the user enters 5 characters, a new activity is called which displays a transparent screen on the top of the current screen.

I want the user to continue entering the digits even when the transparent screen appears. However, since a new activity is called, the user is unable to access the edit-text once the transparent screen appears. Also the keyboard disappears after the transparent screen appears.

Is it possible to allow the user to continue entering the digits even when a new activity (Transparent screen) is called?

[image: Text Entry Activity]

[image: When transparent screen activity is called- keyboard disappears, cant access the edit-text]

Comment: Is there a reason for this design?

Comment: I am working on a research project so this is a part of testing our application.

Comment: I didn't check it, but I guess you might be able to achieve it with static fields, or by creating a "leak" in your first activity. Most definitely it's not in the Best Practice list :)

Comment: Even I was thinking about that. But what should I call of the main activity (text entry) using the variable so that I can access the on-screen keyboard and resume typing the digits?

Comment: I'm really guessing here, but you can try and create a public static method in your activty, and in this method you'll open the keyboard programtically. Call this method from the second one. I'm curious what exception you'll get ;)
Though even if it showed. I'm quite sure you won't be able to type.


InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(linearLayout.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

Comment: Does the transparent thing have to be a new activity?  Or it can just be a view that you unhide in in the existing activity..

Comment: It has to be a new activity. The transparent activity is part of a library, so I cannot use it in the existing activity. I will have to call it explicitly as another activity.